# Offline task management software

Tags: windows, software-rec, tasks

I wish to have an offline task management software that could reside in System tray from where i could manage my tasks for the day.

My OS: Windows 7. should support windows vista & XP as well.

Thanks!

Comment: All of the inputs are great but none of them reside in System Tray..:(

Comment: Task Coach does reside in the system tray and can be set up to start up when Windows starts in the system tray only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the open-source [Task Coach](http://www.taskcoach.org/), which offers task and effort tracking, categorization, prioritization, and more.  A paid ($0.99) iOS app is also available, and they can sync with each other.

Task Coach does reside in the system tray and can be set up to start up when Windows starts in the system tray only.

[image: Screenshot of Task Coach from taskcoach.org]
*This screenshot reflects an old version, though it hasn't changed much*

Answer (score 7):

You should try this [Todolist](http://www.abstractspoon.com/tdl_resources.html) . It may be complex at the first time you use, but once you're used to it, it's pretty useful and productivity.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In line with Docs answer (though a bit more constructive) you could try using notepad++ ( http://notepad-plus-plus.org/ ).

A quick tweak in the preferences will minimize it to the system tray and it also supports text folding, so you could put in additional detail without it cluttering up the top level view.

It also grants the benefit of generating files in plain text so you can easily migrate it to different OS's (and yes, notepad++ runs on Win7, Vista and XP). In addition you can toss the file to someone else and they can open it with any text editor.

If you are looking for a simple, easy to use solution I would recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

do you need separate SW for it? Many email clients have also this function. For example, I use Mozilla Thunderbird with Lightning calendar extension so I can also add some tasks, events etc. It is cross-platform (running on XP, Win 7, and also linux). It is not difficult to sync it with Google Calendar so I can see all planned events and tasks also when I am not in office. It has visual and sound notifications. Very useful for me.

PS: do not know if it can reside in system tray (I think it can), as have email opened for a whole day.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Efigio To Do List](http://www.efigioorganizer.com/efigio-to-do-list-software.html):
It has an interesting feature (among other useful ones):
***Fast ToDo creation directly from system tray (even if application is minimized)***
[image]

Answer (score -6):

If your needs are really simple, there's always notepad :)

Edit: or other obviously simple approaches - like using a spreadsheet. If you must have a link on the System Tray, and can't settle for having a shortcut on the quick launch bar, then please, kindly disregard this suggestion. I find people often look for complicated solutions to simple problems, so just throwing this out there in case it was accidently overlooked.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that this does _not_ meet the OP's requirements.

Comment: I don't think that's clear at all. I find often people look for overly complicated solutions to simple problems. Maybe notepad itself is too simple, but the jist of the suggestion is obvious - use a spreadsheet if you want more.. I'm unconvinced this person really needs a dedicated app. But thanks for the down vote.

Comment: keep it civil, please. If you continue to act rude towards users, your account will be suspended.

Comment: This post is offensive--the way you're writing is condescending and the edit summary seen on the revisions page for this answer is overtly offensive

Comment: But... Notepad!?!!!