# Scheduling/Planning software

Tags: calendar, time-management

Anyone know of software that can track both work scheduled as well as actual work done on the same calendar?  I'd like something that I can use to both plan what I intend to do, record what was done at what time, and use this information to determine whether my planning is off...

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Project) will do that and a whole lot more.  It is fairly easy to get started with and like most Microsoft products, integrates well with other Office programs for easy transfer of data.

Answer (score 1):

For some free alternatives...

---

[TaskJuggler](http://www.taskjuggler.org/) uses code syntax and allows for some very powerful features and chart/work load generation. Similar output to MS Project:

[image: tj image]

I've used this a little bit and can verify that you absolutely can define a project with two "paths" -- planned and actual/delayed. You write the initial project up with an intended set of deadlines and then fill in the actual dates as you progress.

---

[GanttProject](http://www.ganttproject.biz/) is another free task/milestone/project tracking application you can look into.

[image: gantt project]

---

Lastly, [Emacs org-mode](http://orgmode.org/), while it has a steep learning curve, is quite fantastic for tracking tasks, todos, and projects. It has a rich timestamping abilities, so you can add timestamps any time you want to update a task's status. You can also track time spent on subtasks and generate a clock report, set scheduled/deadline dates for tasks, etc.

For what its' worth, I use org-mode almost daily for work and tracking tasks. I learned Emacs just for org-mode and it has been absolutely worth it. I just put up some keybinding cheat sheets on my cube walls for reference.

Check out some of the [screencasts](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-screencasts/index.html) or the page of [tutorials](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/index.html) for more!

---

Good luck with your search.

Answer (score 0):

here is a [similar thread](https://superuser.com/questions/300286/offline-task-management-software), check it. What about suggested [Task Coach](http://www.taskcoach.org/index.html)?

Answer (score 0):

like Typoknig mentioned, Microsoft Project 2010 is a great tool for project management. If you're looking for tips and tricks on how to best use it, check out their [project management training](http://www.microsoft.com/project/en/us/train-learn.aspx) videos and other resources on their website!

Comment: I can't find any training videos there...